# Как выделяется память под классы, выделяется ли она при определении класса?

Tags: c++, классы, память

Как выделяется память под классы, выделяется ли она при определении класса и при создании объекта класса?

Comment: Под класс или под объект класса?

Comment: Также, как и для другой любой  записи в файле

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, и под класс и под объект класса.

Comment: Зависит от кода (определения) класса

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выделение памяти можно разделить на две большие категории:

1. Память распределяемая на этапе компиляции: объекты, содержимое которых известно на этапе компиляции (константы), машинный код функций, различная служебная информация, как то таблицы виртуальных методов, таблицы с информацией о типах, таблицы обработчиков исключений и т.п. Все это попадает в исполняемый файл и память под это все сразу выделяется системой при запуске приложения.
2. Память, распределяемая на этапе выполнения программы: объекты, содержимое которых не известно на этапе компиляции. В этом случае выделение памяти может определяться:

   1. Компилятором - для всех объектов, имеющих время хранение automatic, static, thread local (то бишь созданных без оператора new).
   2. Программистом - для всех объектов, имеющих время хранения dynamic (то бишь созданных посредством оператора new). В этом случае опять возможны два варианта:

      1. Выделение памяти происходит с использованием глобальной или перегруженной функции выделения памяти (обычный синтаксис оператора new).
      2. Выделения памяти не происходит, объект размещается в указанном существующем буфере (синтаксис placement new).

Comment: Стоит заметить, что "placement new" синтаксис - это не только про размещение в существующем буфере, а в общем случае о передаче дополнительных аргументов в функцию аллокации. Например, `new (std::nothrow) int` - тоже использует placement new синтаксис, но предварительно выделенного буфера тут не используется.

Answer (score 5):

Так как C++ - сложный (очень) язык со множеством реализаций на разных архитектурах и агрессивной оптимизацией, рассмотрение всех нюансов оперирования с памятью растянется на длиннопост  (который будет, фактически, плохим переводом львиной доли Стандарта).

Ниже я приведу самые примитивные примеры, которых достаточно для базового понимания ситуации. Оно годится для ответа в школе/вузе, но с ним может быть трудно на собеседовании, особенно если вам попадется *language lawyer*

При определении - нет (если совсем точно - это зависит от компилятора и его настроек). При объявлении экземпляра - есть три варианта.

Все дальнейшие примеры - это просто середина тела какой-то функции:

1. `Class clazz;` - экземпляр создастся **на стеке**
2. `Class* clazz = new Class()` - создастся **на куче**
3. `Class* clazz = new(ptr) Class()` - создастся по адресу ptr - **Placement New** (куда показывает ptr - это уже забота программиста)

Также запись `Class clazz;` - может встретится как поле структуры/класса, но в таком случае память будет выделяться / удаляться в зависимости от жизни экземпляра структуры/класса.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что при placement new память не выделяется. Должна быть выделена уже ранее.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy - это детали реализации в конкретном компиляторе. В частности, оптимизатор может вовсе выкинуть обращения к виртуальным методам и заменить их на прямые вызовы. Более того, VTABLE класс все же таскает с собой в большинстве реализаций.

Comment: Вы напутали выделение памяти и storage duration. Во всех трех случаях память может выделяться как на стеке, так и в куче или даже в отдельной области.

Comment: @user7860670 - вы имеете в виду ситуацию, когда конструктор класса выделяет память?

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду, что запись `Class clazz;` позволяет лишь говорить о том, что объект имеет automatic storage duration. А где выделяется под него память, и выделяется ли вообще - по такой записи судить нельзя. А запись `Class* clazz = new Class()` - только о том, что объект имеет dynamic storage duration. и т.д.

Comment: @user7860670 а по какой тогда записи судить можно?

Comment: Нужен полный контекст. Без [mcve] никак не обойтись.

Comment: Я добавил уточнения насчет контекста

Comment: Все равно неверно судить о выделении память только по storage duration. Даже если `Class clazz;` встретилась внутри обычной функции, то это совсем не значит, что экземляр будет хранится на стеке.

Comment: Но если я попрошу адрес этого объекта, я получу адрес из стекового фрейма.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Не обязательно, вдруг функция вызывается в контексте корутины и память под объекты с automatic storage duration выделяется на куче. Кроме того, попытка взятия адреса может изменить порядок размещения объекта в памяти был только в регистрах а окажется еще и на стеке.

Comment: Это уже тонкости. @user7860670 намекает на то, что оптимизатор может все затолкать в регистры.

Comment: Оптимизатор может изъять почти весь исполнимый код программы. Нужно ли об этом упоминать в ответе на вопрос "где живут объекты"?

Comment: Мы приходим к тому, что если попытаться учесть все нюансы и особенности (а давайте учтем гарвардскую архитектуру, в какую память там пойдет vtable - в память кода или в память данных?) превращает ответ на простой вопрос в толстенную книгу.

Comment: https://github.com/jcmvbkbc/avr-flash-vtbl - а вот тут взяли и поместили в PROGMEM, чтобы RAM сэкономить.

Comment: Ответ можно сделать формально корректным небольшой отпиской, мол, (а) в стандарте нет терминов "куча" и "стек" (поэтому написанное выше формально не гарантируется), и (б) оптимизирующий компилятор может в каких-то отдельных случаях класть объекты куда захочет, по [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: Еще я бы про (1) добавил, что в стеке - если эта строчка внутри функции.

Answer (score 3):

При компиляции определения класса создаются три вещи: код методов, [VTBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) если есть виртуальные методы, [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) если его не отключили при компиляции. Вся эта информация попадает в исполнимый модуль и занимает место в памяти. Её объём во время работы программы не меняется.

Экземпляры класса тоже потребляют память. Каждый раз когда вы создаёте новый экземпляр вы обязаны предоставить ему память в которой он будет существовать.

Comment: Вы тоже напутали выделение памяти и storage duration...

Comment: @user7860670 а вы почему-то убеждены, что вопрошающему нужны не storage duration.

Comment: @gbg Так вопрос был про выделение памяти, а не про storage duration.

Comment: Уговорили. Убрал storage duration. Формально вы правы, на практике ответ стал хуже.